# Add dots/ellipsis on div/span element overflow without using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, constraints

Need to implement functionality similar to what [*dotdotdot*](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) jQuery plugin does 
but cannot use javascript frameworks (like `jquery` or ext).

**Is there any easy way to add the dots to the content of div or span element if content takes more space then element should???
(similar to what css *overflow: ellipsis* setting does)**

Can't use *ellipsis* beacause it doesn't work with many lines when height is limited.

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you specify a little? Why does it have to be similar to `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, but not that?

Comment: @Bohdan: `text-overflow: ellipsis` *is* respected when you set a height.  See the examples at http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#text-overflow.  What browsers have you tested in?

Comment: While developing - in Firefox, but eventualy in all major browsers(IE,FF,Safary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to my problem can seem a little awkward, but it works for me:)

I used a little of CSS:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

and Javascript:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i in spans) {
    var span = spans[i];
    if (/*some condition to filter spans*/) { // just 
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            span.parentNode.style.display ='inline-block';
        }
        if (span.parentNode.clientHeight > 50 ) {
            span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.substr(0, 26) + ' ...';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 36):

Why not using the CSS property text-overflow? It works great as long as you define a width in your tag.

Class in CSS:

```css
.clipped {
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

```html
<div class="clipped" style="width: 100px;" title="This is a long text">This is a long text<div>
```

You can also add the text to the `title` attribute, so the user can see the whole text when hovering over the element.

Comment: The problem is that there can be many lines of the text, how can I make it in case of that?

Comment: @Bohdan Voloshyn - If the text is really very long, just use the first lets say 250 characters for the title, and append '...' at the end.

Comment: I actually started with cutting to 50 characters and append '...' (that's a  requirement :)),

Comment: but when there are many words like *WWWWWWWW* - it puts each word to a separate line and it ends up with 5 rows - the problem is that I can afford only 3 rows. When `overflow: hidden` is used - the content is simply cutted, and therefore '...' is not visible.

Comment: @Bohdan Voloshyn - Are you talking about the title or the div element now? I don't think that you have much control over the title window, it may differ from browser to browser. One possibility would be to write a hidden div and show it only when hovering over the element (with CSS). An example you can find here http://www.bencosweb.com/franz/tooltip_cssplay/index.html .

Comment: @Bohdan Voloshyn Have you got solution of you this problem? I also have same issue...

Answer (score 2):

Works for any number of lines and any width without any javascript - and is responsive. Simply set your max-height to a multiple of your line height: i.e. (22px line height) * (max 3 lines of text) = (max height 66px).

https://codepen.io/freer4/pen/prKLPy

```css
html, body, p { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: sans-serif;line-height:22px;}

.ellipsis{
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:1em;
  position:relative;
}

.ellipsis:before {
  content: "\02026";  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; 
  right:0;
  width: 1.8em; 
  height:22px;
  margin-left: -1.8em;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), white 40%, white);
  z-index:2;
}
.ellipsis::after{
  content:"";
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  float:right;
  background:#FFF;
  width:3em;
  height:22px;
  margin-top:-22px;
  z-index:3;
}

/*For testing*/
.ellipsis{
  max-width:500px;
  text-align:justify;
}
.ellipsis-3{
  max-height:66px;
}

.ellipsis-5{
  max-height:110px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipsis ellipsis-3">
  <p>Here we can have a great many lines of text and it works as we expect it to. Here we can have a great many lines of text and it works as we expect it to. Here we can have a great many lines of text and it works as we expect it to. Here we can have a great many lines of text and it works as we expect it to.</p>  
</div>

<div class="ellipsis ellipsis-5">
  <p>The number of lines shown is easily controlled by setting the max-height of the .ellipsis element. The downsides are the requirement of a wrapping element, and that if the text is precisely as long as your number of lines, you'll get a white area covering the very trailing end of your text. You've been warned. This is just some pushing text to make the element longer. See the ellipsis? Yay.</p>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

This will only work if your elements are not dynamically sized. They will have to have a width set or some other mechanism to keep them from growing to allow more content.

Answer (score 0):

FOR ALL Browser:

```
.dotdot{ white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; max-width:80px}
.dotdot:before { content: '';}

<div class="dotdot">[Button Text Goes here][1]</div>
```